# Failing To Check if Element is Disabled

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have a dropdown with elements that get disabled when conditions are met. In the test, I check them for being disabled, but all tests fail and always return the element state as enabled (Clearly incorrectly. I have ensured that this is not a timing issue - refreshed the page and gave ample wait time with browser sleep - the elements are clearly disabled on the screen). There is an anchor within a list item. Please see image:

[image]

I have tried checking both the list item and the anchor, like so:

```
    var actionDropDownList = $$('[class="dropdown-menu"]').get(1);
    var checkOutButtonState = actionDropDownList.all(by.tagName('li')).get(6);

    actionsButton.click();
    actionDropDownList.all(by.tagName('li')).count().then(function(count){
        console.log('THE NUMBER OF ELEMENTS IN THE DROPDOWN IS...............................................................' + count);
    }) //verify that I have the correct dropdown - yes

    checkOutButtonState.isEnabled().then(function(isEnabled){
        console.log('CHECKING checkOutButton BUTTON STATE: ' + isEnabled);
    }) //log state - shows incorrectly
```

I have also tried checking the button itself for disabled state (the element below is what I tried checking instead of the list element):

```
var checkOutButton = $('[ng-click="item.statusId !== itemStatus.in || checkOut()"]');
```

This failed as well.

Not sure which one I should check and why both are failing. How do I correct this and get it to show that the disabled button is...well, disabled.

---

TEMPORARY ADD ON EDIT:

For simplicity's sake, I am trying:

```
var hasClass = function (element, cls) {
    return element.getAttribute('class').then(function (classes) {
        return classes.split(' ').indexOf(cls) !== -1;
    });

var checkOutButtonState = actionDropDownList.all(by.tagName('li')).get(6);
expect(hasClass(checkOutButtonState, 'disabled')).toBe(true);
```

It still fails, however, despite the element clearly having the class. Alec - your solution throws "function is not defined," I am not sure if I need something else for it to see jasmine. Tried, but can't find anything wrong with it, not sure why I can't get it to work.

Edit:

If I run...since it only appears to have one class:

```
expect(checkOutButtonState.getAttribute('class')).toBe('disabled');
```

I get "expected 'ng-isolate-scope' to be 'disabled'"

Comment: From your screenshot count of list seems 9 and your logs print 10. Are you sure you got the right selector unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I just cut one element off in the screenshot, there are 10. Still messing with alecxe's solution. Apparently this is a common issue, some people recommend element.getAttribute('disabled')).toEqual(true) on github and whatnot. It's essentially what alec does, but simpler (and crappier).

Answer (score 3):

In a quite similar situation I've ended up checking the presence of `disabled`class:

```
expect(checkOutButtonState).toHaveClass("disabled");
```

Where `toHaveClass()` is a [*custom jasmine matcher*](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html):

```
beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toHaveClass: function() {
            return {
                compare: function(actual, expected) {
                    return {
                        pass: actual.getAttribute("class").then(function(classes) {
                            return classes.split(" ").indexOf(expected) !== -1;
                        })
                    };
                }
            };
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: I updated the answer under "Temporary add on," take a look if you have time.

Comment: Sorry, ignore the above comment, I think I might know what the problem is.